# How to integrate automated monitoring/service to a gwt application?

Tags: gwt, tomcat, service, automation

I´ve written a supporting-solution for a little internet service provider using gwt 2.4.
It analyzes a few parameters of customers cable modems (receiving/sending - signal strengthes, frequencies and so on). 
This time, it works only reactive after a support agent clicked the analyze button for a modem in the application.
The application is hosted at a tomcat 7 application server.

Now to my question:
I want to record the modem-parameters of every modem of our infrastructure to a database automated once a day - maybe at night.

Where should I place the code in my gwt application? 
Or did I need a sperate project for doing that?
Or better: where I have to start? :-)

I would be thankful if anyone have an answer for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to include all the monitoring and recording code in a plain Java servlet. You can deploy this servlet with your GWT app in tomcat.

You can then set up a cron job to call the servlet's url. Check out the curl command.

Comment: I never anwered on this, sorry. I did it in this way and it works till now in my company... :-)

Regards, Marc